# Delete multiple lines from an M3U file that does not match pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, m3u

I have an m3u file and I want to delete some lines from it. I know which channels I would like to keep from the m3u file. This list is of channels I want to keep is shorter than the list of channels I don't want.

**Input file**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: TV 1
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3168.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: TK Tuzla
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3164.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: SOS
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3191.ts
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 1
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3190.ts
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 2
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3167.ts
#EXTINF:-1,GB: Discovery
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3166.ts
#EXTINF:-1,GB: NGC
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3201.ts
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 3
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3200.ts
#EXTINF:-1,IT: SKY Sport
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3198.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: Pink Film
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3199.ts
#EXTINF:-1,GB: Sky Sport
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3172.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: N1 Bosna
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3197.ts
#EXTINF:-1,DE: Bundesliga
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3195.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: MTV
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3170.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: Mini TV
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3177.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: M1 Film
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3179.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: Lov I Ribolov
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3196.ts
#EXTINF:-1,ex-Yu: Klasik TV
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3194.ts
```

Above is a shortened list of all channels. I know I would like to keep the following channels:

- All channels starting with `NL:` (case sensitive)
- All channels with `sky sport` in it (not case sensitive)
- All channels with `DE: Bundesliga` in it

**Wanted result**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 1
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3190.ts
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 2
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3167.ts
#EXTINF:-1,NL: NPO 3
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3200.ts
#EXTINF:-1,IT: SKY Sport
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3198.ts
#EXTINF:-1,GB: Sky Sport
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3172.ts
#EXTINF:-1,DE: Bundesliga
http://channel.domain.com:9603/live/YHJKUYII/02490j4/3195.ts
```

I can't get this to work in either `sed`, `awk` or any other bash tool which can do the job. Any ideas?

Comment: Think positive! No, seriously it'll make your software MUCH easier to write and to understand later. When you write requirements that contain negative logic (`Delete multiple lines from an M3U file that does` **not** `match pattern`) you often end up with software that's written with negative logic and so hard to understand (and often wrong due to misunderstanding the [often-double] negative requirements) so just take a second to see if you could come up with a way to write the requirement in a positive way, e.g. `Select multiple lines from an M3U file that match pattern`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
sed -n -r -e '/EXTM3U/p' -e '/NL:|DE: Bundesliga/,+1p' -e '/sky sport/I,+1p'
```

For each matching pattern, it prints the current line and the following line.

`-n` suppresses automatic printing of pattern, `-r` uses extended regular expressions, and `-e` allows to add multiple sed scripts on the same command.

`/EXTM3U/p` is the simplest: it matches lines containing `EXTM3U` and prints them (`p`)

For `'/NL:|DE: Bundesliga/,+1p'`, it matches lines containing `NL:` or `DE: Bundesliga`, and prints it (`p`) as well as the following line (`+1`)

For `/sky sport/I`, `I` makes a case insensitive match.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative `awk` command,

```
 awk '/NL:|DE: Bundesliga/ || tolower($0) ~ /sky sport/ {print; getline; print}'
```

Comment: That will have negative side-effects if `getline` fails, you need to test for that, and it has all of the usual `getline` caveats. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline (and then don't use it anyway as this isn't a good application for getline).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'f{print;f=0} ($2~/^NL:/) || /DE: Bundesliga/ || (tolower($0)~/sky sport/){print;f=1}' file
```